# Ajax form Submit in Spring MVC with Spring Security - 405 Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, ajax-forms

Step1: In Spring Mvc submitting the form using ajax,worked fine.

Step2: Integrating same spring MVC project with spring security(without ajax form submit in spring mvc) also worked fine.

But now when tried to integrate same (step2 project) spring MVC + Spring security and also introducing ajax form submit for spring mvc form end up with the error 405 on the browser

**405: method not allowed, Request method 'POST' not supported**

```
   **General**
    Request URL:http://localhost:8080/Springmvc-ajax-security/submitForm.web
    Request Method:POST
    Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
    Remote Address:[::1]:8080

**Response header**
Allow:GET
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length:1085
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Sat, 26 Mar 2016 12:12:00 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block



**Request header**
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:117
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:JSESSIONID=019622188DB97DEF5F2D1AE716032C41
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/Springmvc-ajax-security/helloWorld.web
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

**Request payload**
{"studentName":"Noorus","studentBranch":"CS","studentDept":"computer","_csrf":"b68fbffe-d7a0-40eb-9edc-74d0f6408556"}
```

StudentController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/submitForm.web", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Student  submittedFromData(@RequestBody Student student, HttpServletRequest request) { 
        return student;
    }
```

student.jsp

```
    <body>

    <form:form id="submitForm" action="submitForm.web" method="post"
        commandName="student">

    <fieldset style="width: 300px;">
        <legend>Student details</legend>
        <ol>
            <li><label for=studentName>Student Name</label> <form:input
                    path="studentName" name="studentName" type="text"
                    placeholder="First and last name" /></li>
            <li>
                <p>
                    <label for=studentBranch>Student Branch</label>
                    <form:input path="studentBranch" name="studentBranch" type="text" />
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>
                    <label for=studentDept>Student Department</label>
                    <form:input path="studentDept" name="studentDept" type="text"
                        required="true" />
                </p>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset style="width: 300px;">
        <input id="submitId" type="submit" value="Submit Form">
    </fieldset>
</form:form>
</body>

<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/submit.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    alert("welcome to js page");
    $('#submitForm').submit(function(e) {
        var frm = $('#submitForm');
        e.preventDefault();

        var data = {}
        var Form = this;

        //Gather Data also remove undefined keys(buttons)
        $.each(this, function(i, v){
            var input = $(v);
            data[input.attr("name")] = input.val();
            delete data["undefined"];
        });
        $.ajax({
            contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            dataType : 'json',
            data : JSON.stringify(data),
            success : function(callback){
                alert("Response: Name: "+callback.studentName+"  Branch: "+callback.studentBranch+"  Department: "+callback.studentDept);
                $(this).html("Success!");
            },
            error : function(){
                $(this).html("Error!");
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Student.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="studentId")
    Long studentId;

    @Column(name="studentName")
    String studentName;

    @Column(name="studentDept")
    String studentDept;

    @Column(name="studentBranch")
    String studentBranch;   

    public Student() {
        super();
    }

  getter & setter
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you enable csrf checking in spring security? I think it is enabled by default in version 4+. If so you should pass the tokens also.

Comment: @ Jovin Thariyath using spring 4.2.5, and token can be seen in the request payload

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, where I was using Ajax with Spring Security and in my case disabling the csrf worked for my security configuration.

```
   @Configuration
   public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter   {

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
   httpSecurity.csrf().disable();

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your payload is sending _csrf which is like extra data in your object.{"studentName":"Noorus","studentBranch":"CS","studentDept":"computer",**"_csrf":"b68fbffe-d7a0-40eb-9edc-74d0f6408556"**}

But if you see your model class it does not have _csrf field. it could be the reason where request is looking for exact match method and it is not finding so it is showing 405.

Answer (score -1):

`@RequestMapping(value="/submitForm.web", method = RequestMethod.GET)`

Dont you mean `method = RequestMethod.POST`

Comment: Apologies. At the time I only saw `RequestMethod.GET` in the example code which also would have given the error for a POST. However as the gaurab states (and subsequently changed the code0, this was not the only issue causing the problem.